# how to create two fixed size views and one view spanned between them in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I want to create a screen

with two fixed size areas: one aligned to left, one to the right

and in between them another area which spans all the rest of the area?

If I make the middle view with property `fill_parent` it will catch all the area to the 3rd child.

what will be the effective property when `layout_weight=0.X` and `layout_width=20dp`.?

======

I have a linearLayout with `orientation= horizontal`.

It has a child with `layout_weight=0.X` and also `layout_width=20dp`.

What will be the effective property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a horizontal `LinearLayout` with the first child with a fixed width (e.g. `layout_width="20dp"`), the second child with a non-zero weight (e.g. `layout_weight="1"`) and the third with a fixed width (e.g. `layout_width="20dp"`), then you should get the first aligned to the left, the third aligned to the right and the third filling the area between them.

It's also possible to do this with a `RelativeLayout`, but I'll leave that as the above solution should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

     <View android:id="@+id/view1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <View android:id="@+id/view3"
           android:layout_width="20dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You should use `android:layout_weight`.

Comment: `android:layout_weight="1"` will not push the 3rd view out of the visible area?

Comment: Set `android:layout_weight="1"` will make the view stretchable, and =0 will make it not be stretched. In this case, you want View2 to be stretchable, so it will give up some space for View3, which is not stretched. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight) is the docs.